# Comparing output value of SQL query with a number

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a registration form that has 10 groups that people can join. Each group can only hold 3 users. My logic is as follows for limiting each group:

1. create a query that returns the amount of times a group number occurs in the database.
2. fetch the amount of rows that number occurs
3. if the amount of rows fetched is more than 3, it means that that more than 3 users have registered.

I have tried to tackle this with a simple scenario of not being able to join groupnumber 8 before attempting to do it with all the groups:

```
if (!($link = mysqli_connect('connection', 'name', 'password', 'databasename'))) {
    die('Error: Could not connect' . mysql_connect_error());
} else {
    $result = "SELECT id FROM student WHERE groupnumber = '8'";

    if (mysqli_query($link, $result)) {

        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if (($rowcount) < 3) {

            echo 'you have successfully joined';
        } else {

            'you cannot join this group';
        }
    }
}
```

the code: `you have successfully joined` never gets executed regardless of the amount of people have chosen group number 8 in the database.

Comment: Sorry, i have just seen your comment and reply now. I will digest what you have said and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: The code works perfectly well, but now i am trying to find a way to make it applicable for all my groups, as opposed to just group 8. I do not want to duplicate the code each time and change the variable number to the corresponding group number. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the whole code for you, but I will get you started. The code you have has many problems. Let me show you an example of how you count rows in the MySQL and how you fetch that number in PHP:

```
<?php

// Enable error reporting for mysqli and connect to MySQL
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$link = new mysqli('connection', 'name', 'password', 'databasename');
$link->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // Mandatory charset!

$groupnumber = 8; // <-- this is your input value

// Prepare -> bind -> execute -> get result
$stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM student WHERE groupnumber=?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $groupnumber);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$numberOfRows = $result->fetch_row()[0]; // COUNT(*) will be in the first row in the first cell

// Rest of your logic follows
if ($numberOfRows < 3) {
    echo 'you have successfully joined';
} else {

    'you cannot join this group';
}
```

When doing this approach be wary of race conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have been breaking my head into figuring out a solution for all the groups. I have changed $groupnumber =8 into $groupnumber = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), but i don't how to get the sql to chose the corresponding index when the user attempts to pick a group. Could you kindly provide me more guidance, i am very weak at programming but i am dedicated. Thank you sir.

Comment: I think this could be done in SQL. My advice would be to ask another question, but don't include PHP code, include only SQL code and the dump of your tables/columns. Explain the desired output and the problem in SQL terms only. There are great SQL experts here and if you provide enough details, they should help you write the query properly. If this cannot be done in SQL then you should write some PHP logic for this.

Comment: Thank you @Dharman. You have been very kind and helpful. All the best